# Genitivendung bei Abkürzung

Tags: grammaticality, abbreviation

Es wird folgender deutscher Satz betrachtet:

> Die Steuerung des Blockheizkraftwerks erfolgt manuell.

Ich möchte `Blockheizkraftwerk` durch seine gängige Abkürzung `BHKW` ersetzen.

Welche der Varianten ist die richtige in meinem Fall?

> Die Steuerung des BHKW erfolgt manuell.

oder

> Die Steuerung des BHKWs erfolgt manuell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Beides ist möglich**.

Insbesondere dann, wenn der Kasus der Abkürzung durch den Artikel deutlich wird, kann man guten Gewissens auf das 's' verzichten. Man kann also sowohl *des BHKW*, als auch *des BHKWs* schreiben.

Worauf man verzichten sollte sind Apostrophe. Also bitte **kein** BHKW's.

Bei Pluralbildungen sollte man allerdings (besonders dann, wenn die Grundform auch schon mit *die* gebildet wird) ein s anhängen (etwa die GmbH - die GmbHs). Für das BHKW also entsprechend *die BHKWs* (Nom. Pl.), bzw. *der BHKWs* (Gen. Pl.).

Für weitere Informationen [hier zur Dudenredaktion](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen) oder [dieser Website](https://www.textpertise.de/sprachtipp-07-2006.html).

**EDIT:**

Dies bezieht sich nur auf sogenannte Initialwörter/Akronyme. Abkürzungen mit einem Punkt an Ende (um es zu vereinfachen) folgen anderen Regeln, die auch unterm Dudenlink zu finden sind. Ebenfalls kann es [Ausnahmen bei Abkürzungen geben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abk%C3%BCrzung#Pluralbildung_und_Deklination), "die nie in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet werden (z.B. RAe (= Rechtsanwälte))."

Comment: Inwiefern empfiehlt sich hier eine doppelte Verneinung? Und der Genitivplural wird mit "der" gebildet, also "die Steuerung der BHKW erfolgt manuell" bzw. "die Steuerung der BHKA erfolgt manuell" wenn es weibliche Anlagen wären.

Comment: @userunknown Doppelte Verneinung erkenne ich keine. Klär mich da bitte auf ^^. Das Beispiel mit "die BHKW" war als Nom.Pl. gedacht, Evtl war das uneindeutig. Sinnvoll und empfohlen ist die Verwendung des s im Plural etwa bei Begriffen wie "die GmbH", z.B. "Die Geschäftsführer der GmbHs gehen morgen essen." Ansonsten ist es abhängig vom Artikel, des Stils und des Kontexts. Im Plural wird das s aber meist gesetzt.

Comment: Damit meine ich "kein BHKW's" zu schreiben und zusätzlich "BHKW's" durchzustreichen. Wir schreiben doch auch nicht "Ich aß keinen <s>Apfel</s>."

Comment: Interessanter als Genitive mit "s" sind hier solche mit "n" und "e": Anzutreffen, aber auch disputierbar sind Schreibweisen wie: "Die Haltung der VHSn [Volkshochschulen] in Deutschland zum Thema xyz...", "Die Anstrengungen der KVVe [Krankenversicherungsverbände] im letzten Jahr..." - Solche Abkürzungsflexionen findet man in Fachtexten, nicht jedoch in Texten, die sich an eine breitere Öffentlichkeit wenden.

Comment: Ebenfalls zu diskutieren wäre, wenn man denn die Nützlichkeit des BHKWs im Genitiv Singular anerkennt, wie man mit anderen Kasus im Plural umgeht? Wollen wir mehr BHKWe bauen? Oder mehr BHKWs? Sollten wir den BHKWn mehr Aufmerksamkeit schenken? Oder den BHKWs?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann folgt man den oben verlinkten Regeln des Dudens gibt es wenig zu diskutieren "Bei Initialwörtern steht im Plural gegebenenfalls die Endung -s (und nicht die Endung des zugrunde liegenden Wortes). - die EKGs (nicht: die EKGe), die AGs (nicht: die AGen)". Endet die Abkürzung, wie im Fall der VHS, selbst auf s [passiert nichts](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/108827/sbj/plural-mit-s-bei-s-am-wortende/), auch wenn das zu Uneindeutigkeiten führen kann, wie dein Beispiel zeigt. Da kommt es dann auf den Kontext an.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Formatierung mit Durchstreichen empfiehlt sich, um auf einen Blick erkennbar zu machen, dass es sich um eine falsche Schreibweise handelt. So kann auch einem flüchtigen Leser bei völliger Nichtbeachtung des Kontexts nicht entgehen, dass der Text *kein* Beispiel für die falsche Schreibweise darstellt. (Freilich ist das in der Interpretation keine doppelte Verneinung; die (einfache) Verneinung findet allein im Text statt, während das Durchstreichen lediglich eine Art Hervorhebung ohne Bedeutungsänderung ist.)